# Winterbash in Area51?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, winter-bash-2013

I know Area51 is rather different from all other StackExchange sites in terms of code base and functionality, but is there any chance that Area51 will participate in the Winterbash next year? I'd love to wear my hats there too!

Comment: Weird, http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/ appears to use same codebase as the rest of the sites (it even  got the new top bar) but no winter bash.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Probably because there is no adapted ways to earn hats on this site so it wasn't implemented at all.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname I agree. Many of the hat unlock procedures wouldn't work. Anyway.... why don't just enable wearing on area51 hats earned on the main sites?

Comment: Hopefully Area51 will have been replaced by their new process this time next year...

Comment: I'm looking into the prospect of letting users wear hats earned on other sites on A51. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't have a setting this year that allows a site to display user's hats (earned on other sites) without letting users earn hats on that site. If we did, that's what Area 51 would have, as well as any private betas that start during the event.

It's not going to be possible to implement this for the current Winter Bash event, but we'll certainly keep it on our list for things to consider for next year.